# MVC 3 Output Cache Problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-3

ASP.Net MVC 3 RTM. I am trying to use the OutputCache attribute in an action, but doesn't appear to be working. Here is the Http Request and Response.

> ```
> Request URL:http://localhost/MyApp/Employee.mvc/GetImage?userId=myUserId
> Request Method:GET
> Status Code:200 OK
> Request Headers
> Accept:*/*
> Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
> Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
> Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
> Cache-Control:no-cache
> Connection:keep-alive
> Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=sessionIdStuff
> Host:localhost
> Pragma:no-cache
> Referer:http://localhost/MyApp/Employee/Review/1/Index
> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US)
> ```
>
> AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/9.0.597.98 Safari/534.13
>       Query String Parameters
>       userId:myUser
>       Response Headers
>       Cache-Control:private, no-store, max-age=3484
>
> ```
> Content-Length:1428
> Content-Type:image/jpeg
> Date:Wed, 16 Feb 2011 22:59:14 GMT
> Expires:Wed, 16 Feb 2011 23:57:19 GMT
>
> Last-Modified:Wed, 16 Feb 2011 22:57:19 GMT
> Server:Microsoft-IIS/5.1
> Vary:*
> X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
> X-AspNetMvc-Version:3.0
> X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
> ```

Here is the controller:

```
        [HttpGet, OutputCache(Location= OutputCacheLocation.Client, VaryByParam="userId", Duration=3600, NoStore=true)]
        public FileContentResult GetImage(string userId)
        {
            byte[] result;

            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                result = client.DownloadData(string.Format(IntranetUrl, userId));
            }

            return File(result, "image/jpeg");
        }
```

and my View:

```
<img alt="Employee Picture" src='@Url.Action("GetImage", "Employee", new { userId = Model.UserId, area=""})' width="75px" height="100px" />
```

I tried comparing with other static images that are getting cached and the only differences where these lines:

> Cache-Control:private, no-store,
>   max-age=3484

This is included in my action, but not in the static images. Also, the static images had an ETag, but my action response did not.

Can anyone help why this might not be cached in the browser?

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 2):

Try remove: NoStore=true (or set NoStore = false), and it'll work :)